# Facing in joining tables

Tags: sql

There are five tables

- `Items` (ItemNo,productName)
- `ProductBatch` (productBatchId,ItemNo,batchName,purchaseRate)
- `DamageStock` (AdjustmentId,date,description)
- `DamageStockItem` (damageStockDetailsId,AdjustmentId,productBatchId)
- `StockPosting` (serialNumber,productBatchId,outwardQuantity,voucherType).

My aim is that to retrieve all information from above tables for each damage stock item through this query:

```
select  
    P1.ItemNo, B1.productBatchId, S1.serialNumber, 
    P1.productName, S1.outwardQuantity, DS.damageStockDetailsId
FROM         
    Items AS P1 
INNER JOIN    
    ProductBatch AS B1 ON P1.ItemNo = B1.ItemNo
INNER JOIN   
    StockPosting AS S1 ON B1.productBatchId = S1.productBatchId
INNER JOIN   
    DamageStockItem as DS on DS.productBatchId = B1.productBatchId
INNER JOIN   
    DamageStock AS MASTER1 ON MASTER1 .AdjustmentId = DS.ItemAdjustmentId
WHERE 
    S1.voucherType = 'Damage Stock' 
    AND DS.ItemAdjustmentId = '10001'
```

but it shows duplicate values for `damageStockDetailsId` which is the primary key of `DamageStockItem` table and I don't know that there is any problem in the relationships between these tables or no and also I solved this problem when I made a relation between StockPosting table and DamageStock , I put the primary key of StockPosting table in DamageStockItem as foreign key and it did not show any duplicate value. I want to know that this relationship is correct or no. I need your ideas regarding this issue.

Comment: Please correct the inconsistent table names DamageStockDetails/DamageStockItem and DamageStcokMaster/DamageStock. I just did that, but my edit was reverted.

Comment: @nlu Please don't alter the question like that.  It does not appear to be the issue in this case, but for some questions, simple inconsistencies like that can actually be the problem.

Comment: Add Master1.Date to your select statement; rerun. Are the values for it different when records are "duplicated"?  If so it explains your duplicate.  To resolve, drop join to DamageStock. None of its columns are in the  select or where; or group by all fields in the select.

Comment: yes sir, i have many occurrences of damage stock for the same product batch id.

Comment: You're query is fine aside from you don't need `INNER JOIN   
    DamageStock AS MASTER1 ON MASTER1 .AdjustmentId = DS.ItemAdjustmentId` which is causing the perceived duplication of records

Comment: sir,i removed the inner join of Master 1 but i am still getting duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

You can have several damageStockDetailsId per AdjustmentId in your table DamageStockItem (or DamageStockDetails, whatever it is called).

As those are connected to an AdjustmentId you should output that too, to see where the (seemingly same) damageStockDetailsIds belong to.